# Winston 3.2.1 - TypeError: logger.error is not a function

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, winston

Updated to winston 3.2.1 recently. I was testing some new functionality and expected to log an error. Apperantly I found my server crashed. The reason is -> `TypeError: logger.error is not a function`

Has anyone faced that issue yet?

My winston config:

```
const options: LoggerOptions = {
  level: 'info',
  format: format.combine(
    format.timestamp({
      format: 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss'
    }),
    format.json()
  ),
  transports: [
    new transports.Console(),
    new transports.File({ filename: 'logs/error.log', level: 'error' }),
    new transports.File({ filename: 'combined.log' })
  ]
};

const logger: Logger = createLogger(options);

export default logger;
```

It was imported to other modules as `logger.error(err.message, err);` and everything worked fine until now.

I looked at index.d.ts and the Logger, and the log/error/info etc, so error indeed accepts message & meta but I keep having that typeError.

I also tried to pass as an `infoObject` - I get the same error.

```
interface Logger extends NodeJSStream.Transform {
    silent: boolean;
    format: logform.Format;
    levels: Config.AbstractConfigSetLevels;
    level: string;
    transports: Transport[];
    exceptions: ExceptionHandler;
    profilers: object;
    exitOnError: Function | boolean;

    log: LogMethod;
    add(transport: Transport): Logger;
    remove(transport: Transport): Logger;
    clear(): Logger;
    close(): Logger;

    // for cli and npm levels
    error: LeveledLogMethod;
    warn: LeveledLogMethod;
    help: LeveledLogMethod;
    data: LeveledLogMethod;
    info: LeveledLogMethod;
    debug: LeveledLogMethod;
    prompt: LeveledLogMethod;
    http: LeveledLogMethod;
    verbose: LeveledLogMethod;
    input: LeveledLogMethod;
    silly: LeveledLogMethod;

    // for syslog levels only
    emerg: LeveledLogMethod;
    alert: LeveledLogMethod;
    crit: LeveledLogMethod;
    warning: LeveledLogMethod;
    notice: LeveledLogMethod;

    query(options?: QueryOptions, callback?: (err: Error, results: any) => void): any;
    stream(options?: any): NodeJS.ReadableStream;

    startTimer(): Profiler;
    profile(id: string | number, meta?: LogEntry): Logger;

    configure(options: LoggerOptions): void;

    child(options: Object): Logger;

    new(options?: LoggerOptions): Logger;
  }
```

error prop->

```
  interface LeveledLogMethod {
    (message: string, callback: LogCallback): Logger;
    (message: string, meta: any, callback: LogCallback): Logger;
    (message: string, ...meta: any[]): Logger;
    (infoObject: object): Logger;
  }
```